# How do I install ruby properly on M2 Mac Sonoma 14.1

Tags: ruby, macos, macos-sonoma

Edit 2: Tried installing with `asdf` instead and getting the same/similar build error, so that's reassuring I guess:

```
ld: warning: ignoring duplicate libraries: '-lruby.3.2'
compiling wait.c
linking shared-object etc.bundle
closure.c:300:14: error: call to undeclared function 'ffi_prep_closure'; ISO C99 and later do not support implicit function declarations [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    result = ffi_prep_closure(pcl, cif, callback, (void *)(data->self));
             ^
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [closure.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [ext/fiddle/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
compiling date_strptime.c
ld: warning: ignoring duplicate libraries: '-lruby.3.2'
linking shared-object io/nonblock.bundle
ld: warning: ignoring duplicate libraries: '-lruby.3.2'
linking shared-object io/wait.bundle
ld: warning: ignoring duplicate libraries: '-lruby.3.2'
linking shared-object io/console.bundle
ld: warning: ignoring duplicate libraries: '-lruby.3.2'
1 warning generated.
linking shared-object bigdecimal.bundle
ld: warning: ignoring duplicate libraries: '-lruby.3.2'
linking shared-object date_core.bundle
ld: warning: ignoring duplicate libraries: '-lruby.3.2'
make: *** [build-ext] Error 2
```

Edit 1:
Here's the output towards the end of the error file:

```
https://pastebin.com/HXZva8w9
```

**Background:** Flutter development environment, trying to install cocoapods, but that's** failing, asking me to install updated ruby version.

**Trying to install ruby:** Tried various methods with `rbenv`, `brew` and `rvm` - all eventually failing with my last attempt being this:

```
Davids-MacBook-Pro-4:~ daveshirman$ rbenv install 3.2.2
To follow progress, use 'tail -f /var/folders/bg/hx4gy68d1sn9w8yyxc5r9g800000gn/T/ruby-build.20231030135906.17084.log' or pass --verbose
Downloading openssl-3.1.4.tar.gz...
-> https://dqw8nmjcqpjn7.cloudfront.net/840af5366ab9b522bde525826be3ef0fb0af81c6a9ebd84caa600fea1731eee3
Installing openssl-3.1.4...
Installed openssl-3.1.4 to /Users/daveshirman/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2

Downloading ruby-3.2.2.tar.gz...
-> https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/3.2/ruby-3.2.2.tar.gz
Installing ruby-3.2.2...
ruby-build: using readline from homebrew
ruby-build: using libyaml from homebrew
ruby-build: using gmp from homebrew

BUILD FAILED (macOS 14.1 using ruby-build 20231025)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/bg/hx4gy68d1sn9w8yyxc5r9g800000gn/T/ruby-build.20231030135906.17084.dykRrZ
Results logged to /var/folders/bg/hx4gy68d1sn9w8yyxc5r9g800000gn/T/ruby-build.20231030135906.17084.log

Last 10 log lines:
ld: warning: ignoring duplicate libraries: '-lruby.3.2'
ld: warning: ignoring duplicate libraries: '-lruby.3.2'
linking shared-object -test-/string.bundle
ld: warning: ignoring duplicate libraries: '-lruby.3.2'
1 warning generated.
linking shared-object bigdecimal.bundle
ld: warning: ignoring duplicate libraries: '-lruby.3.2'
linking shared-object date_core.bundle
ld: warning: ignoring duplicate libraries: '-lruby.3.2'
make: *** [build-ext] Error 2
```

Can someone please give me a set of steps that work?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you check the file mentioned and include more of the log. This doesn't say what went wrong. Feel free to paste as much as possible, I can edit to cut it down to relevant parts.

Comment: You're looking for a line towards the end of that log file which says "ld: error" or similar.

Comment: I've added the output into pastebin, thanks!

Comment: there are 3 solutions proposed here https://github.com/ffi/ffi/issues/869#issuecomment-1233000037

Answer (score -2, accepted):

1. Open `Terminal` in Rosetta mode
2. `rbenv install <version>`
3. Adding init command `eval "$(rbenv init - bash)"` to `~/.bash_profile`
4. Restart Terminal

Then everything functioned as normal.

Comment: This answer would be improved if you explained what those commands do. Does `ruby -v` say something like `[x86_64-darwinYY]`? I think you just installed an x86 version of Ruby which will run in emulation. Emulation brings its own problems.